# how to avoid url to be inserted into textfield while drag and drop

Tags: javascript

I have a textarea in which an ondrop function is specified.

```
 <textarea id="xyz"  ondragover="event.preventDefault()" ondrop="doDrop(event)"  ></textarea>
```

Iam trying to drag text  data into textarea based upon a condition using javascript. if the condition is false the url of the page is getting dragged into the textarea . how can i avoid that? instead of url data i should get blank string. please help

```
 function doDrop(event)
            {
                var links = event.dataTransfer.getData("text/uri-list").split("\n");

                var vals2=links.toString().split("_");
                try{
                if(vals2[2]==1)
                    {
                var val=$('textarea#xyz').val();

                document.getElementById("tableHead").value+= vals2[1]+",";   

                event.preventDefault();
            }
            else
                {

                    alert("You cannot drag this element");

                }
                }
                catch(e)
                {
                     document.getElementById("tableHead").value="";
                     alert("You cannot drag this element"); 

                }
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing the url bit inside the `doDrop()` method?

Comment: yeah. i tried to make the textfield value to null. Even then url is getting inserted

Comment: Could you share a JSFiddle with the doDrop() code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event.preventDefault() should be placed inside the else brackets to stop the standard behavior of putting the text into the dragged area.

Comment: could you vote the answer up so that others see that it works :)